# How to find multiple values within curly braces from a string

Tags: javascript

How to find multiple values within curly braces from a string using JavaScript.
E.g.

```
string = https://test.com/tour/reception/@{name1}/@{name2}/test/@{name3};
```

I tried with this, `/@{[A-Za-z0-9À-ÿ_ .-]*}/` but don't know how to get the values matched.

How can you get the `name1`, `name2` and `name3` from the string?

Comment: You need a regex. Did you tried anything?

Comment: yes i tried with this ,
    /@{[A-Za-z0-9À-ÿ_ .-]*}/;
but don't know how to get the values matched.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regex to match text surrounded by curly braces. You'll want to use `+?` to match non-greedily.

```
var string = "https://test.com/tour/reception/@{name1}/@{name2}/test/@{name3}";
var matches = string.match(/{.+?}/g);
```

Now `matches` is `["{name1}", "{name2}", "{name3}"]`.

Comment: and optionaly then matches.map(function(match){ return match.replace(/{(.*?)}/,"$1")}), in order to get just the tokens

Comment: @Gael No, that's not necessary, instead of `match` use `exec`. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34806080/2025923)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this RegEx.

```
/{.*?}/g
```

**E.g.**

```
var s = 'https://test.com/tour/reception/@{name1}/@{name2}/test/@{name3};';
var res = s.match(/{.*?}/g);
for (var r in res)
{
  console.log(res[r]);
}
```

This outputs

```
{name1}
{name2}
{name3}
```

Comment: I've written regEx but want to know how to fetch al the values matched.?

Comment: just use match  function in JS like this: `matches = your_string_name.match(/{.*?}/g);` and `matches` variable will be holding all the values

Answer (score 1):

While other answers show how to extract the text with curly brackets, none of them has really answered the question.

> How can you get the `name1`, `name2` and `name3` from the string?

You can use [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [`String#substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) methods.

```js
var str = "https://test.com/tour/reception/@{name1}/@{name2}/test/@{name3};";

// Copy the string
var copy = str;
var index,
  matches = []; // To store results

// Till there is string wrapped in curly braces
while ((index = copy.indexOf('{')) !== -1) {
  var closingIndex = copy.indexOf('}');
  matches.push(copy.substring(index + 1, closingIndex));

  // Update the string to remove the first match
  copy = copy.substring(closingIndex + 1);
}

console.log(matches);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(matches, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

---

Using RegEx

```
/{([^}]*)}/
```

With global flag.

[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zW8mW1/1)

**RegEx Explanation:**

1. `{`: Match `{` literally
2. `([^}]*)`: Match anything that is not `}` any number of times and put the match result in the first captured group.
3. `}`: Match closing bracket `}`
4. `g`: Global flag

[image: Regex Visualization]

In JavaScript, get the results by using [`RegExp#exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

```js
var regex = /{([^}]*)}/g;

var str = "https://test.com/tour/reception/@{name1}/@{name2}/test/@{name3};";
var matches = [];

while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
  // match[1] is the first captured group
  matches.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(matches);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(matches, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non-regex syntax (perhaps for more clarity):

```
var str = "https://test.com/tour/reception/@{name1}/@{name2}/test/@{name3}";
var bopen = false;
var valIndex = {
  istart: 0,
  iend: 0
};
values = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < str.length ; i++) {
  var ch = str.charAt(i);
  if (ch == '{') {
    bopen = true;
    valIndex.istart = i;
}
  if (ch == '}' && bopen == true){
    bopen = false;
    valIndex.iend = i;
    values.push(str.substring(valIndex.istart + 1, valIndex.iend));
  }
}
alert(values);
```

The alerted result is an array of strings : name1,name2,name3

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6095asub/).