# Get only the string inside a curly brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have number of strings like

```
var str="#{ZyDt8spGZOA.mI8uHaT7o47}+#{z3PENrRf0cn.mI8uHaT7o47}+#{lhUBSvCMPWu.mI8uHaT7o47}+#{YNpiWU7fw9m.mI8uHaT7o47}";
```

I need to get the content only inside the curly bracket to an array. (In the above case array of length 4).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Demom https://jsfiddle.net/btp7jjg7/2/

Comment: You can try [`substring`and `indexOf` OR `/{([^}]*)}/`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34806080/2025923)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var found = [],          
    rxp = /{([^}]+)}/g,
    str = "#{ZyDt8spGZOA.mI8uHaT7o47}+#{z3PENrRf0cn.mI8uHaT7o47}+#{lhUBSvCMPWu.mI8uHaT7o47}+#{YNpiWU7fw9m.mI8uHaT7o47}",
    mat;

    while( mat = rxp.exec( str ) ) {
          found.push(mat[1]);
    }

    alert(found);
```

Comment: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/btp7jjg7/7/)

Answer (score 1):

## use following code

array = str.split("}+#{");

after doing this reult will look like

```
array[0] = "#{ZyDt8spGZOA.mI8uHaT7o47"  
array[1] = "z3PENrRf0cn.mI8uHaT7o47"  
array[2] = "lhUBSvCMPWu.mI8uHaT7o47"  
array[3] = "YNpiWU7fw9m.mI8uHaT7o47}"
```

after this just remove extra string form array[0] and array[3]

**array[0]  = array[0].substring(2, array[0].length)

array[3]  = array[3].substring(0, array[3].length-1)**